# Efficient and Clean way for writting this code - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have been working on this code which sum up the score from 3 Assignments and 1 Test from my dataframe and generate mark (A,B,C,D,F) according to the scores.

This is my dataframe.

```
 StudentId, Assignment1, Assignment2, Assignment3, Test
 xxxxxxxx       11           15            7        50
 yyyyyyyy        5           10            2        31
```

This is my code to Sum up the  Score and Generate Mark

```
SumScoreX = []
GradeX = []
for x in xrange(len(df)):
   A1, A2, A3, T1 = df['Assignment1'][x], df['Assignment2'][x],df['Assignment3'][x], df['Test'][x]
    SumScore = np.sum([A1,A2,A3,T1])
    if SumScore < 51:
        Grade = 'F'
    elif SumScore == 50 and SumScore < 60:
        Grade = 'D'
    elif SumScore == 60 and SumScore < 70:
        Grade = 'C'
    elif SumScore == 70 and SumScore < 80:
        Grade = 'B'
    elif SumScore <= 80:
        Grade = 'A'
    SumScoreX.append(np.round(SumScore))
    GradeX.append(Grade)
```

My code is looking very unclean. I feel like there should be a better way to write a code with similar function to this code.

Please advise me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the following DF:

```
In [100]: df
Out[100]:
  StudentId  Assignment1  Assignment2  Assignment3  Test
0  xxxxxxxx           11           15            7    50
1  yyyyyyyy            5           10            2    31
```

First calculate the `score`:

```
In [101]: df['score'] = df.filter(regex=r'(?:Assignment\d*|Test)').sum(1)
```

now we can categorize the score using [pd.cut()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) method:

```
In [102]: df['grade'] = pd.cut(df.score, bins=[0, 51, 60, 70, 80, 200], labels=list('FDCBA'))

In [103]: df
Out[103]:
  StudentId  Assignment1  Assignment2  Assignment3  Test  score grade
0  xxxxxxxx           11           15            7    50     83     A
1  yyyyyyyy            5           10            2    31     48     F
```

Comment: Oh, wow this is awesome. Thanks you, I've learn something new too.

Comment: @Niche.P, glad i could help :)